# Change the value for multiple items in list python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a nested list:

```
Table=[['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','','']]
```

I have randomly placed some values in `Table` and now I want to place other things in the 2D neighbours of those values. E.g.:

```
Table=[['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','value','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','','']]
```

Then i want to add:

```
Table=[['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','1','',''],
       ['','1','value','1',''],
       ['','','1','',''],
       ['','','','','']]
```

## Under is all my code i don't know why but it would accept it in any other format sorry :/

```
def add_nukes():
    pos=j.index('nuke')
    if "nuke" not in j[0]:j[pos+1]='1'
        if "nuke" not in j[-1]: 
            j[pos-1] = "1"
            board[pos][i-1]="1"
            board[i+1][pos]="1"

import random

size=150

if size%2==1:
    size+=1

board = [[" "]*size for i in range(size)] 
bombs = 25

all_cells = ["nuke"] * bombs + [" "] * (size - bombs) 

random.shuffle(all_cells)

board = [all_cells[i:i+10] for i in range(0, size, 10)]

count=0

for j in board:
    for i in range(len(j)):
        count+=1
        if "nuke" in j[i]:
            add_nukes()
        elif "nuke" in j[i]:
            add_nukes()

for item in board:
    print item
```

Comment: Sorry - this isn't super clear.. can you simplify?  Also, what have you tried?  SO won't just solve problems for you without an attempted solution

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you like to elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am tryin to make the minesweeper game with lists so lets say i have a bomb in list 5 3rd position 
i want to add in the 5th list before and after the bomb a 1 and in the 4th and 6th list in the 3rd position a 1 
just like minesweeper 
(hope i helped :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Aurel Bílý mentioned, there are four neighbouring coordinates in which you need to add value for the specific case: `[Table[y - 1][x], Table[y + 1][x], Table[y, x - 1], Table[y, x + 1]]`.

In order to do that, you must first ensure that these coordinates are valid and do not throw an `IndexError` exception. After you make sure that this coordinates are valid, you can safely add them in your table.

The code below demonstrates this:

```
Table=[['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','value','',''],
       ['','','','',''],
       ['','','','','']]

def isInBounds(Table,x,y):
    return 0 <= x < len(Table) and 0 <= y < len(Table[0])

def addValue(Table,x,y,value):
    if isInBounds(Table,x,y):
        Table[x][y] = value

def addValuesAround(Table,x,y,value):
    addValue(Table,x-1,y,value)
    addValue(Table,x,y-1,value)
    addValue(Table,x+1,y,value)
    addValue(Table,x,y+1,value)

addValuesAround(Table,3,2,1)
for elem in Table:
    print(elem)
```

This will return:

```
['', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '']
['', '', 1, '', '']
['', 1, 'value', 1, '']
['', '', 1, '', '']
['', '', '', '', '']
```

**EDIT:**

I think I got it, using both of our codes. Just be sure to change the syntax of the `print` function, because you're using Python 2.7 and I use Python 3.6:

```
import random

def isInBounds(Table,x,y):
    return 0 <= x < len(Table) and 0 <= y < len(Table[0])

def addValue(Table,x,y,value):
    if isInBounds(Table,x,y):
        Table[x][y] = value

def addValuesAround(Table,x,y,value):
    addValue(Table,x-1,y,value)
    addValue(Table,x,y-1,value)
    addValue(Table,x+1,y,value)
    addValue(Table,x,y+1,value)

size=150

if size%2==1:
    size+=1

board = [[" " for i in range(size)] for i in range(size)] 
bombs = 25

all_cells = ["nuke"] * bombs + [" "] * (size - bombs) 

random.shuffle(all_cells)

board = [all_cells[i:i+10] for i in range(0, size, 10)]

count=0

for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board[i])):
       if board[i][j] == 'nuke':
           addValuesAround(board,i,j,"1")

for item in board:
    print(item)
```

This will give an instance of a board like this:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1']
['1', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', '1']
['nuke', '1', '1', '1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', 'nuke']
['1', '1', 'nuke', '1', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1']
[' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', '1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '1', ' ', '1', ' ']
[' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1']
['1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ']
[' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', 'nuke', '1', 'nuke', '1', ' ']
```

Comment: i have managed to attach my code could you give it a look and tell me because i am trying to do what you are saying in another way but it adds "1" in places that it shouldn't and i don't know why ;-;

Comment: Sure thing, but could you please fix the indentation and the syntax of your `add_nukes` function?

Comment: yea the last 2 went off sorry, but now i am trying to use it with your code and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

Any value in `Table` is identified uniquely by its `x` and `y` coordinates, i.e. the element in the 2nd column (`x == 1` because 0-indexed) and 3rd row (`y == 2`) is `Table[y][x] == Table[2][1]`.

The four immediate neighbours of any cell `A` are the cells with `x` one away from `A` OR with `y` one away from `A`. If `A` is `Table[y][x]`, then the neighbours are `[Table[y - 1][x], Table[y + 1][x], Table[y, x - 1], Table[y, x + 1]]`.